# What did daughters (roughly 19 and 11) affectionately call their mothers in the 19th century (1883ish)?

Tags: american-english, history, nineteenth-century-english

I'm writing a short historical fiction essay on Mercy Brown and family, and was wondering what Mary Brown (19) and Mercy (11) would have called her while she was on her death bed with consumption. From what I've seen, they are a middle class family in Exeter, Rhode Island, and the particular incident I'm writing about (Mary Olive Brown's death), is in 1883.

Comment: Take a look at Louisa May Alcott, e.g. 'Jo's Boys', which you almost certainly ought to do, with such a project.

Comment: I would guess 'Mama' (certainly in England and probably also in the US, though with a different pronunciation).